# ExecutorService java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, сервер, многопоточность, сокеты

Использую ExecutorService для многопоточного сервера. При запуске в Эклипсе выдается исключение java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
Все работает нормально без ExecutorService.

```
final ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(1237);
        final ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
        {

            service.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {try{
                    // code
}catch(Exception e){try {welcomeSocket.close();service.shutdown(); } catch (IOException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}}
                    }}});}
```

Что неверно в моем коде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И не удивительно. Вы в бесконечном цикле раздаёте бесконечные задания сервису.

Что делает сервис при получении нового задания? [Документация](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29) на ваш `service`:

> Creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. [...] Calls to execute will reuse previously constructed threads if available. If no existing thread is available, a new thread will be created and added to the pool.

то есть

> Создаёт пул потоков, который создаёт при необходимости новые потоки, но использует повторно старые, если они доступны. [...] Вызовы `execute` будут использовать ранее созданные потоки, если они свободны. Если нет, будет создан новый поток и добавлен в пул.

То есть, поскольку ваши задания не заканчиваются, то повторного использования потоков не происходит, и вы в цикле создаёте один за одним новые потоки.

Не удивительно, что рано или поздно они заканчиваются.

Вам нужно пересмотреть архитектуру вашего кода. В таком виде функционировать не будет в принципе.

Comment: Спасибо! Значит перед `service.submit(new Runnable() {` нужно определить что установлено новое соединение с клиентом. не знаете как определить, что это случилось?

Comment: @CodeGust: Ах, это сервер! У вас в коде этого нет. Я бы делал так: в главном потоке открывал соединение с клиентом, и когда оно откроется, отдавал бы работу с клиентом в новый поток.